# WebKit back button doesn't respond when pressed

Tags: ios, swift, webkit

I have a simple back button set up to bring the user back after they've visited a webpage. Testing it out, it seems that the back button is not doing anything:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let stories = storyData[indexPath.row]
        guard let storyImageUrl = URL(string: stories.url) else {return}
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: storyImageUrl))
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        view = webView

        // Back button
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.goBack))
    }

@objc func goBack() {
        if webView.canGoBack {
            webView.goBack()
        } else {
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Pressing the button simply does nothing - I've checked various similar questions and the code looks correct. What's going wrong here?

Comment: from the code in didSelectRow, it doesn't seem like you are pushing a new view controller(with webView) on the navigation Stack. You should be typically setting up the self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem on the viewcontroller which has your webView

Comment: @Deepika Yes I'm just setting `view = webView`, I was under the impression that `webView.goBack()` was responsible for returning from that view? Sorry if that doesn't make sense I'm pretty new (this is a learning project)... I'll try pushing a new view controller, how would that be done in this scenario?

Comment: I have added an answer below. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can push a new controller in multiple ways, for instance using segue or instantiating the controller from storyboard.

I'll brief the latter one.
Create a ViewController with a webView in your storyboard and give it a storyboard ID as WebViewController. Create a UIViewController subclass named WebViewController and link it with the storyboard. Then use the below code to push it.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let stories = storyData[indexPath.row]
        guard let storyImageUrl = URL(string: stories.url) else {return}
        let webController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WebViewController") as! WebViewController
        webController.urlToLoad = storyImageUrl
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(webController, animated: true)           
}
```

In the above example, the assumption is that your current View controller is embedded inside UINavigationViewController.
Then in your WebViewController viewDidLoad you can set up your back button

```
var urlToLoad: String?
override func viewDidLoad() {
       // do your stuff
       // Back button
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.goBack))
         guard let storyImageUrl = URL(string: urlToLoad) else {return}
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: storyImageUrl))

}
@objc func goBack() {
        if webView.canGoBack {
            webView.goBack()
        } else {
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }
}
```

You can use segue as well.
Hope this helped.

Comment: How would my new webController know which story to load though? I still need WebKit on my main view controller and will have to use`webView.load(URLRequest(url: storyImageUrl))`. That's where I was getting hung up - I'd load that and set `view = webView` which I guess just loaded in the current view instead of a new view controller.

Comment: I have updated the answer. You can actually pass the urlToLoad to your new Controller and it can load the url you want to. So every time you select a row, it will load a new viewcontroller with your url loaded. I have not tested the above code but it should be something similar.. I hope you can get the idea.